# Lucee OAuth2 O365

Tags: oauth-2.0, office365, cfml, lucee

I had an application that checked an email address (cfmail tag) for expected information (in XML format), parsed that information, and then dumped it into a database.  We were using basic authentication with O365.  I believe their switch to OAuth has broken our system.

I am looking for resources,tutorials, and advice on how to implement an OAuth layer to our Lucee application that will allow us to check that email as before.  I have spent some time Googling, but I am a little confused as to where to start.

Comment: Microsoft offers an [alternative to OAuth called "app password"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/using-app-passwords-with-apps-that-don-t-support-two-step-verification-5896ed9b-4263-e681-128a-a6f2979a7944). That might already to the trick for your use case.

Comment: @Alex - I am unable to find the App Password setting in our Active Directory settings.  Can you assist?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to reenable basic authentication in O365 - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-deprecation-in-exchange-online-september/ba-p/3609437

However, this will only keep your application working until the end of 2022, when Microsoft will permanently disable Basic Authentication. We are also looking for a solution to accessing O365 email from Lucee.

Comment: Hey - did you manage to find a solution to using Lucee & Office365?

Comment: I got some great help on the Lucee forum here https://dev.lucee.org/t/check-email-on-o365-with-oauth/11389 . In that thread there is an example cfc that handles the interaction with the Graph API.